# Selecting Spinner Item doesen't trigger onItemSelected - method

Tags: java, android, fragment, spinner, onitemselectedlistener

I have a settings fragment with 2 spinners in it. I'm not able to execute code written into the onItemSelected-method. There are no errors or exceptions.

I searched many similiar questions but none of the solutions worked for me. I have no idea what to try next.

```
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Getting the instance of Spinner and applying OnItemSelectedListener on it
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);

        Spinner spinnerBetrag = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerBetrag);
        Spinner spinnerDetails = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerDetails);

        spinnerBetrag.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinnerDetails.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
          //>>Problem: Code within this method is never beeing executed<<
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `onCreateView()` method to return the `view`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Getting the instance of Spinner and applying OnItemSelectedListener on it
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);

    Spinner spinnerBetrag = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerBetrag);
    Spinner spinnerDetails = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerDetails);

    spinnerBetrag.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinnerDetails.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    return view;  // add this instead
}
```

Also for your `onItemSelected()` add

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

     Spinner spinner = (Spinner) parent;
     if(spinner.getId() == R.id.spinnerBetrag)
     {
       Log.d("Spinner 1","selected");                 
     }
     else if(spinner.getId() == R.id.spinnerDetails)
     {
        Log.d("Spinner 2","selected");    
     }

}
```

Comment: Had to wait for the few minutes to pass. Marked it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your return statement in `onCreateView` to

```
return view;
```

Your current return statement is inflating a whole new view